# how fix invalid url in magento

Tags: magento-1, error, url

Invalid base url type

```
Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(620): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Invalid base ur...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('validation', NULL)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php(250): Mage::getBaseUrl('validation')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php(206): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="styl...', Array, Array, NULL)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\templatemela\MAG110227_1\template\page\html\head.phtml(63): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->getCssJsHtml()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\templa...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\templatemela\MAG110227_1\template\page\1column.phtml(40): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\templa...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(556): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(389): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(417): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called an invalid base url type called `validation` **Mage::getBaseUrl('validation')** from your block file **Head.php** which is inside the method **&_prepareStaticAndSkinElements**. The exception is thrown as no such url type exists.

Remove this line Mage::getBaseUrl('validation') , this exception will not be thrown.

Besides that its certainly not right to edit the magento core files.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php(250):

```
    /*** Possible URL types****/
    const URL_TYPE_LINK                   = 'link';
    const URL_TYPE_DIRECT_LINK            = 'direct_link';
    const URL_TYPE_WEB                    = 'web';
    const URL_TYPE_SKIN                   = 'skin';
    const URL_TYPE_JS                     = 'js';
    const URL_TYPE_MEDIA                  = 'media';
```